# Network Setup + Hotspot with redirect to webpage

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, captive-portal

**What I have** 
I have (ROUTER 2)TP-LINK WR841ND with DD wrt latest version with sputnik hotspot enabled

(Access Point) 2.4GHz 300Mbps 9dBi Outdoor CPE CPE210

My friend with internet also have a (ROUTER 1) TP-LINK WR841ND with default software

**What I want to do** 
I want to get redirect all users who connect to final antenna to see my landing page ( my website)

I want to get internet from R2 ( internet access ) to Router 1 ( with splash page, sputnik) and forward internet signal thru lan on Antenna

**What I tried** 
Connected Router 1 to Router 2 to get internet ( made this with bridge connection) and then connected to Antenna with Lan cable ( I made this connection with Bridge also and made Antenna an Access Point.

**What problem I have** 
I have internet on Access Point on Antenna but Sputnik doesn't work If I make bridge connection its like it doesn't filter any traffic if I connect them this way.

It worked only one way ( If I connect router 2 with dd wrt directly to internet and then connect antenna , this way the Hotspot works but Owner of Router 1 doesn't want to change firmware on his router.

**Conclusion**

1. Internet -> R2 -> R1 (Sputnik Hotspot Router)-> Antenna (CPE 210) -> Doesn't work (R1 doesn't filter traffic)
2. Internet R1 (Sputnik Hotspot Router)-> Antenna (CPE 210) -> Works ( but is not good because friend doesn't want to change his firmware of router)

**Questions**

How to configure R1 (Sputnik Hotspot Router)? , Bridge connection didn't work for me.

Picture to better understand:

[image: Picture to better understand]

Comment: A picture of what you're trying to do would be nice as your explanation is quite confusing...